# Only stories are showing in board in JIRA. I want all Epics, Stories, Tasks, Sub-taks to see in board

Tags: jira

In JIRA Board, only "stories" are showing

Filter for JIRA from (vertical3 dot > Board setting > General > Filter > Edit Filter Query)

```
project = NAP ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

Here I can **see** all the **EPICS, STORIES, SUB-TASKS**. I tried to change it to

```
project = NAP AND issuetype in (standardIssueTypes(), subTaskIssueTypes()) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

NAP is project name

But, it is also same only. As standardIssueTypes(Bug, Epic, Story, Tasks) & subTaskIssueTypes(Sub-tasks), together is ALL

But, when I am going to board, it is still showing only "stories"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtasks don't show up in a backlog view by design. However you can configure your backlog to see the subtasks as jira issue id's under their associated Story or Task. In your Board Configuration, go to Card Layout and under Backlog choose "Sub-Tasks" and add it. Now in your backlog at the bottom of each card you'll see any subtasks created for that issue. There won't be details there, but it will at least show you if there are any subtasks associated to that story.

Comment: Great. One more thing. I have seen somewhere in a screenshot there it was showing in the dropdown. What you have said is 90% satisfactory.

Comment: Is this a screenshot that you've seen in the backlog view? I know in the active sprint if you have your board configured with swimlanes based on the Story then you will see subtasks under the parent story, but in the backlog view I've never seen this before. Its possible it was a plugin that provided this view in the backlog. Alternatively, you CAN view subtasks in the backlog under their parent issue if you're using a Kanban board with backlog view, but this isn't available for Scrum boards.

Comment: Not sure if it was backlog view/active spring I have seen. What are you saying I will try that one

Answer (score 1):

The Epics appears on the right side when you're browsing the backlog view. Also, you can use the swimlanes (board configurations) to group by Epics in the board view. But to have the Epics as an issue to track progress and so, this is not the common behavior of the Jira board.

As for the rest of the issue types, make sure you have permission to view the issues. As by default everything shows in the board whether Scrum or Kanban, nothing is needed to have everything showing in the board.

Comment: So, will it not show sub-tasks & tasks in board?

Comment: It will show everything in the board unless you specified something else.

Comment: THat is the issue I am facing

Comment: Would you share a screenshot on how you want to the board to look like, from the description in the question, it seems that "only" user stories appears in the board. By board you mean the Active Sprint view, right? And the default behavior is all the issue types are included into that view unless other specified.

Comment: For now board shows only 'stories'? Does it not show 'sub-tasks' & 'tasks' in board?